# "Trouble Connecting Python Backend Hosted on PythonAnywhere with Frontend on Hostinger"

Tags: python, reactjs, pythonanywhere

I am currently struggling to connect my backend, written in Python and hosted on PythonAnywhere, with my frontend, built in React and hosted on Hostinger. While the frontend receives the initial communication, the connection is abruptly terminated as if blocked. Both the routes and the DOM are correctly set. Interestingly, everything works perfectly in my development environment, but issues arise only in the live version. Any suggestions on what might be causing this discrepancy or how to resolve it would be enormously helpful. Thanks in advance for any insights or assistance.

Over the course of our efforts, we have attempted several solutions to establish a successful connection between the frontend and backend.

CORS Configuration: We attempted to adjust the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) configurations to allow the frontend and backend to communicate despite being on different servers.

Endpoint Verification: We double-checked all API endpoints to ensure the frontend is calling the correct backend routes.

Environment Variables: We made sure all necessary environment variables were correctly defined and accessible in the live environment.

Debugging Logs: We reviewed the server logs for potential issues or errors during the connection process.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. The frontend successfully makes the initial contact with the backend, but the connection is immediately terminated. This is peculiar because, in our development environment, everything functions flawlessly.

Ideally, the frontend (React) on Hostinger should be able to send a request to the backend (Python) on PythonAnywhere. The backend then processes this request and returns a response to the frontend. The frontend should then be able to receive this response and update the user interface accordingly without any communication blockages or interruptions. We are striving to replicate this seamless interaction in our live environment.

Comment: Are you using a free account on PA?  If so, you will not able to reach an external service (unless it's on the allow-list).  Also, have you checked your web app's error logs on PA?

Comment: Hello ! thanks for the answer, its paid account, and the error is 2023-06-14 OSError: write error
OSError: write error and am not being able still to make it work

Comment: Could you check what do you see in the server log for those `OSError`s in the error log?  It looks like there's some timeout and the client disconnects.

Comment: your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
2023-06-16 02:47:31 your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds,  watching on huge lines i found this